# how can I change the font size in runtime generated button in firemonkey desktop application

Tags: winforms, delphi, firemonkey

I want to change the font size in runtime generated buttons in my firemonkey desktop application in delphi xe5, I tried:

```
BArray[I].Font.Family:='Arial';
BArray[I].Font.Size:=40;
```

But all buttons are with small and default font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove stylings first

```
BArray[i].StyledSettings:=[]
```